# Why does creating this comparator give me: "- control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]" warning?

Tags: c, eclipse, scope, comparator

I don't understand why the warning happens because the return values are not in a conditional loop. At least one of the statements must execute and therefore return something.
Here is the code:

```
int qsort_compare (const void * a, const void * b){
    if (*(char *)a == *(char *)b) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (*(char *)a > *(char *)b) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I assumed that it may be a scope issue so I changed it to this, which resolved the warning:

```
   int qsort_compare (const void * a, const void * b){
        int val;
        if (*(char *)a == *(char *)b) {
            val = 0;
        }
        else if (*(char *)a > *(char *)b) {
            val = 1;
        }
        else {
            val = -1;
        }     
        return val;
    }
```

However, could someone please explain why the if-elseif-else structure allowed for the warning to happen? Particularly, why wouldn't the system be designed to understand that I am returning something in at least one of the if-elseif-else statements?

Comment: Not sure about your question, but you could greatly simplify it all: `return (*(char*)a) - (*(char*)b);`.

Comment: @Amit: It most likely is OK in this case but [it's not a good idea to propagate this idiom](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/subtraction-is-not-comparison).

Comment: I compiled the initial posted code, using `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99` and it compiled with no errors nor warnings.  have you actually posted the real code via copy and paste or is this something you typed into the question?

Comment: This is the real code copied and pasted. Oddly enough, after running the second version of the code after the first version of the code on gcc again, the warning has disappeared. Thanks guys. I think it was just a matter of the order that I chosen to rebuild and write the code.